# React Native IOS project loading image from node_modules instead of local after xcode upgrade

Tags: xcode, image, react-native, xcode8

I recently upgrades my xcode to the latest version (8.3.3), prior to this upgrade, I was able to see the image I want in my app with this code:
`<Image source={require('../images/burger.png')}/>`

After the upgrade however, the image that loads is some random image that is used later in my code for my date picker. Upon using the inspector, this image has the following path:

```
__packager_asset:
true
height:
64
scale:
1
uri:
"http://localhost:8081/assets/node_modules/react-native-datepicker/date_icon.png?platform=ios&hash=1edd5017f455b09c608e175b1285c06d"
width:
64
```

Any thoughts on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following for some reason fixed this issue:
`watchman watch-del-all`
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
`npm start -- -- reset-cache`